# Generate baseline profile android for authenticated screen

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, microbenchmark

Android support generate baseline profile to improve performance. By using micro benchmark to interact with UI to get something on screen.

Docs here: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/benchmarking/macrobenchmark-overview

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/baselineprofiles/create-baselineprofile

But by using function `startActivityAndAwait` i only can open login screen, so I could not interact on private screen (logged in screen). I am using `firebase auth` for login function.

```
@LargeTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class SampleStartupBenchmark {
    @get:Rule
    val benchmarkRule = MacrobenchmarkRule()

    @Test
    fun startup() = benchmarkRule.measureRepeated(
        packageName = TARGET_PACKAGE,
        metrics = listOf(StartupTimingMetric()),
        iterations = DEFAULT_ITERATIONS,
        setupBlock = {
            // Press home button before each run to ensure the starting activity isn't visible.
            pressHome()
        }
    ) {
        // starts default launch activity
        startActivityAndWait()
    }
}
```

The question is how to interact with **private screen** to generate expecting `baseline profile` file?

Comment: @ShubhamKumarGupta I answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure another ways but I have to have a login step.

###### Main function

```
fun MacrobenchmarkScope.startBenchmark() {
    pressHome()
    startActivityAndWait()

    loginByPhone()   

    // After login, do another steps
}
```

###### Login function

```
fun MacrobenchmarkScope.loginByPhone() {
    waitAndClickElement("phoneLoginButton")

    setTextFieldValue("phoneNumberTextField", "1222223333")

    // Send OPT Next button
    waitAndClickElement("sendOTPButton")

    setTextFieldValue("smsVerifyTextField", "123456")

    // SMS verify Next button
    waitAndClickElement("verifyOTPButton")
}
```

###### Some helpers

```
fun MacrobenchmarkScope.waitAndClickElement(res: String) {
    val btnSelector = By.res(res)
    device.wait(Until.hasObject(btnSelector), 5000)

    val buttonObject = device.findObject(btnSelector)
    if (buttonObject == null) {
        Log.e("waitAndClickElement", "error at res=$res")
    }

    buttonObject.click()
}

fun MacrobenchmarkScope.setTextFieldValue(res: String, value: String) {
    val textFieldSelector = By.res(res)
    device.wait(Until.hasObject(textFieldSelector), 5_500)

    val textFieldObject = device.findObject(textFieldSelector)

    if (textFieldObject == null) {
        Log.e("setTextFieldValue", "error at res=$res")
    }

    textFieldObject.text = value
}
```

Hope this help someone!